# How to Extends apps into SmartWatch

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sony-smartwatch

I'm developing android apps for smartwatch and smartphone. The application on smartphone is finished. The application has service. It will receive information from machine (status,info,etc).I wonder If I want to develop smartWatch what should I do next?

Do I have to add reference from my application into smartwatch app?like add project library from package to package?

Do I have to declare the service in androidManifest at smartwatch app?

Thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are referring to the Sony Smartwatch?  If so, see here for a guide on how to get started:

http://developer.sonymobile.com/2013/03/13/develop-apps-for-smartwatch-smart-wireless-headset-pro-with-the-new-sony-add-on-sdk/